# How do I pull a XML tag with &amp; and assign to another XML field

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

Apologies for the stupid question, but I searched and still couldn't find.  (if I'm just searching the wrong terms, add a comment and I'll delete this and go find it)

Long story short: existing code uses this code.  We had it choke on some XML records that we recreated from the source data, using code a couple of us wrote.  We narrowed it down to the fact that our code is converting & to `&amp;`, but that's causing the below query to fail and we don't understand why.  We're using a gnarly convert to do a replace on the `&amp;` as a bandaid to get this working, but I'd rather have it work correctly.

Here's my code.  Without the `&amp;` it works.  With it, I get 'illegal name character'.  Why?  I'm extracting the value as text, which would be `blah &amp; blah`,

```
DECLARE @xml_doc XML, @xmlfirst XML
SET @xml_doc= '<A><B><C>blah &amp; blah</C></B></A>'
select TOP 1 CAST (X.Y.value('./C[1]', 'varchar(max)') as xml)
    FROM @xml_doc.nodes('/A/B')X(Y)
```

Comment: Why you again cast it to XML ? if you run this query without cast then it perfectly working. - `SET @xml_doc= '<A><B><C>blah &amp; blah</C></B></A>'
select TOP 1 X.Y.value('./C[1]', 'varchar(100)')
    FROM @xml_doc.nodes('/A/B')X(Y) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation

`X.Y.value('(./C)[1]', 'varchar(4000)')` decode `&amp;` back to `&` (this is the behaviour of value method). This means that `X.Y.value('(./C)[1]', 'varchar(max)')` returns `blah & blah`. Then the conversion of `blah & blah` to XML generates this "error" / exception because `blah & blah` isn't a valid XML (within valid XML, `&` should be encoded as `&amp;`).

Solution #1: if you want to get the encoded inner text of  (`&amp;`) AS *XML*

```
SELECT  X.Y.query('./C/text()')
FROM    @xml_doc.nodes('/A/B')X(Y)
```

returns `blah &amp; blah`

Solution #2: if you want to get the decoded inner text  of  (`&`)

```
SELECT  X.Y.value('./C[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    @xml_doc.nodes('/A/B')X(Y)
```

returns `blah & blah`